# Will lists inherit the edit form from it's Custom Content Type?

Tags: list, content-type

I have created a custom content type and I would like to have all lists that use that content type use it's edit/new forms.  Below is the XML i have in my Elements.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ContentType ID="0x0100211ACDF9A8F75C4190D46F1ADCF5015604308633d0aadc3f41809a6430a81fe0151b"
               Name="TestContentType - TestContentType"
               Group="Custom Content Types"
               Description="This is a test.  This is only a test."
               Inherits="FALSE"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
    </FieldRefs>
    <XmlDocuments>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
        <FormUrls xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
          <Edit>_layouts/TestContentType/TestContentEdit.aspx</Edit>
          <New>_layouts/TestContentType/TestContentNew.aspx</New>
        </FormUrls>
      </XmlDocument>
    </XmlDocuments>
  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

But when I click "Add Item" in my list that is using this content type the standard form comes up.  Am I going at this wrong?

Comment: Did you test with new list after the feature was activated? I guess it may not work with list that already exist when you activated the feature.

Comment: How are you adding the content type to the list? Also, is the content type the default on the list?

Answer (score 1):

Never tried it this way, however I use the following method.

- I basically create a list definition and assign the custom form to it.
- Then I create my lists from the definition in code.

May be of some use to you.

I create a List Definition and deploy it to the site.
My List Definition schema file has the following:

```
...
<Forms>
      <Form Type="DisplayForm" SetupPath="features\FeatureName_Feature1\ListDefinitionName\CustomDisplayForm.aspx"
                Url="Forms/DispForm.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" UseLegacyForm="TRUE" />
      <Form Type="EditForm" SetupPath="features\FeatureName_Feature1\ListDefinitionName\CustomEditForm.aspx"
                Url="Forms/EditForm.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" UseLegacyForm="TRUE" />
      <Form Type="NewForm" Url="Forms/Upload.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="NewFormDialog" Path="EditDlg.htm">
...
```

The set up path is where my custom forms are located and in my case, thats in the sharepoint hive in the feature directory under templates.